# writing Laravel query - count of related model is positive

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Unable to write query in Laravel. I am quite new in Laravel and I am not used to write queries using Eloquent model yet.

I have two models: `Translation` and `Category`.
Each `Translation` has One `Category`. Translation has fields `lang_from_code` and `lang_to_code`. I have FK defined in DB (those were created automatically during migration).

This took me a while, but at the end I have defined models like this:

```
class Translation extends Model
{
    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
    }        
}
```

and

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function translations() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Translation');
    }
}
```

What I need is to write query like this: "Get one random category from all categories from given list (non-technical) which has at leat one translation from lang1 to lang2".

Query would look like this:

```
select * from categories c
where c.is_technical = 0 and c.id in (1,2,3,4,5..)
and (select count(*) from translations t where t.category_id = c.id and t.lang_from_code = 'givencode1' and t.lang_to_code = 'givencode2')) > 0
```

and then random category would be taken.

The best I could write is like this:

```
$cat = str_split ($cat); //comma seperated category ids
$lang_from = 'lv';
$lang_to = 'en';
$category = Category::where('is_technical', '=', 0)->whereIn('id', $cat)->orderByRaw("RAND()")->first();
```

However, I do not know how to write "has at least translation from this category" and also " adding languages from and to.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Category::has('translations')`

Updated to include translations of a certain type. You'll need to amend as necessary!

Something like this might work:

```
$category = Category::whereHas('translations', function($query) use ($givencode1, $givencode2) {
                $query->where('lang_from_code', $givencode1)
                      ->where('lang_to_code', $givencode2);
            })
            ->where('is_technical', false)
            ->orderByRaw('RAND()')
            ->first();
```

Comment: `has` and `whereHas` are perfect for exactly this!

Comment: I am sorry, but I forget to mention that i need translations exactly from given language. I have updated my description.

Comment: No worries, as @alexrussell said, whereHas() should cover you! Have updated answer, although you'll need to amend with whatever field you want to query translations with